# Optimising network code

Tags: go, network-programming

I have a Go server that takes input from a number of TCP clients that stream in data.  The format is a custom format and the end delimiter could appear within the byte stream so it uses bytes stuffing to get around this issue.

I am looking for hotspots in my code and this throws up a HUGE one and I'm sure it could be made more efficient but I'm not quite sure how at the moment given the provided Go functions.

The code is below and pprof shows the hotspot to be `popPacketFromBuffer` command.  This looks at the current buffer, after each byte has been received and looks for the endDelimiter on it's own.  If there is 2 of them in a row then it is within the packet itself.

I did look at using `ReadBytes()` instead of `ReadByte()` but it looks like I need to specify a delimiter and I'm fearful that this will cut off a packet mid stream?  And also in any case would this be more efficient than what I am doing anyway?

Within the `popPacketFromBuffer` function it is the for loop that is the hotspot.

Any ideas?

```
// Read client data from channel
func (c *Client) listen() {

    reader := bufio.NewReader(c.conn)

    clientBuffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

    for {
        c.conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(c.timeoutDuration))

        byte, err := reader.ReadByte()

        if err != nil {
            c.conn.Close()
            c.server.onClientConnectionClosed(c, err)
            return
        }

        wrErr := clientBuffer.WriteByte(byte)
        if wrErr != nil {
            log.Println("Write Error:", wrErr)
        }

        packet := popPacketFromBuffer(clientBuffer)
        if packet != nil {
            c.receiveMutex.Lock()
            packetSize := uint64(len(packet))
            c.bytesReceived += packetSize
            c.receiveMutex.Unlock()

            packetBuffer := bytes.NewBuffer(packet)

            b, err := uncompress(packetBuffer.Bytes())
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Unzip Error:", err)
            } else {
                c.server.onNewMessage(c, b)
            }
        }

    }
}

func popPacketFromBuffer(buffer *bytes.Buffer) []byte {

    bufferLength := buffer.Len()

    if bufferLength >= 125000 { // 1MB in bytes is roughly this
        log.Println("Buffer is too large ", bufferLength)
        buffer.Reset()
        return nil
    }

    tempBuffer := buffer.Bytes()
    length := len(tempBuffer)

    // Return on zero length buffer submission
    if length == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    endOfPacket := -1

    // Determine the endOfPacket position by looking for an instance of our delimiter
    for i := 0; i < length-1; i++ {
        if tempBuffer[i] == endDelimiter {
            if tempBuffer[i+1] == endDelimiter {
                i++
            } else {
                // We found a single delimiter, so consider this the end of a packet
                endOfPacket = i - 2
                break
            }
        }
    }

    if endOfPacket != -1 {
        // Grab the contents of the provided packet
        extractedPacket := buffer.Bytes()

        // Extract the last byte as we were super greedy with the read operation to check for stuffing
        carryByte := extractedPacket[len(extractedPacket)-1]

        // Clear the main buffer now we have extracted a packet from it
        buffer.Reset()

        // Add the carryByte over to our new buffer
        buffer.WriteByte(carryByte)

        // Ensure packet begins with a valid startDelimiter
        if extractedPacket[0] != startDelimiter {
            log.Println("Popped a packet without a valid start delimiter")
            return nil
        }

        // Remove the start and end caps
        slice := extractedPacket[1 : len(extractedPacket)-2]

        return deStuffPacket(slice)
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you call `popPacketFromBuffer()` each time every single byte received from connection. However `popPacketFromBuffer()` copy hole buffer and inspect for delimeters every byte each tyme. Maybe this is overwhelming. For me you don't need loop

```
for i := 0; i < length-1; i++ {
        if tempBuffer[i] == endDelimiter {
            if tempBuffer[i+1] == endDelimiter {
                i++
            } else {
                // We found a single delimiter, so consider this the end of a packet
                endOfPacket = i - 2
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

in `popPacketFromBuffer()` Maybe instead of loop just testing last two bytes

```
if (buffer[len(buffer)-2] == endDelimiter) && (buffer[len(buffer)-1] != endDelimiter){
    //It's a packet
}
```

would be enough for purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I think that makes sense so will give that a go.  Did you mean both of them to be Len(buffer)-1 ?

Comment: Excuse me it's a typo

Comment: Great thanks. Worked really well.  In the end I went for `if ((tempBuffer[length-3] != endDelimiter) && (tempBuffer[length-2] == endDelimiter)) && (tempBuffer[length-1] == startDelimiter){` so that it would make sure it was at the end of a packet